# ExtJS Twitter timeline

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch, jsonp

I am trying to build a simple twitter timeline feature into one of my apps, but falling short of knowledge and cannot really find any decent tutorials online.

Is there a different way in using JSON and JSONP request in ExtJS?

Code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=NynasBo&count=2',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});​
```

Response:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=NynasBo&count=2&_dc=1331218369365 Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Suspecting it should only be a JSONP request...

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use JSONP for the same. So, either it will be request like this:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
   url: 'YOUR JSONP URL',
   callbackName: 'someCallbackFunctionName',
   success: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Else you have to use ScriptTagProxy like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=NynasBo&count=2'
    }
});
```